# Waldspurger's formula and toric periods — classical and adelic versions

Tags: automorphic-forms, l-functions

As far as I know, there are two versions of Waldspurger's formula (classical and adelic), which can be vaguely stated as follows

- (Classical version) Let $f$ be a half-integral weight modular form of weight $k/2$ (where $k$ is odd), level $N$ and character $\chi$ and $F = \operatorname{Sh}(f)$ be its Shimura correspondent in $S_{k-1}(N/2, \chi^2)$. Then $|a_d(f)|^2$, (square of) Fourier coefficients of $f$ for square-free $d$, can be represented as $L(1/2, F \otimes \chi_d)$, the special $L$-value of quadratic twist of $F$.
- (Adelic version, brought from [Horawa's notes on Zydor's lectures on periods of automorphic forms](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/horawa/math_678_periods.pdf)) Let $\pi$ be an automorphic cuspidal representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$ and $\phi = \bigotimes_v \phi_v \in\pi$ be an automorphic form. Let $T \leq \mathrm{GL}_2$ be a non-split torus. Then the square of the toric period is equal to product of special $L$-values and local periods:
  $$
  |\mathcal{P}_T(\phi)|^2 = \bigg|\int_{T(\mathbb{A}_F) / T(F)} \phi(t) dt\bigg|^2 = c\cdot L(1/2, \pi) \cdot L(1/2, \pi \otimes \eta) \cdot \prod_v \mathcal{L}_v(\phi_v).
  $$

I wonder how the adelic version can be thought as a generalization of the classical version. To be precise, I can't find a connection with toric periods and Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight modular forms (there's even nothing about Shimura correspondence in the adelic statement. Note that Waldspurger mention about the classical result in the introduction of his original paper). Is it possible to somewhat *adelize* the classical statement as follows: for an automorphic cuspidal representation $\pi'$ of $\operatorname{Mp}_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$ (or maybe 2-cover of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$), and a corresponding automorphic representation $\pi$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$ via Shimura correspondence, can we related a certain kind of period of $\pi'$ with special $L$-values of quadratic twists of $\pi$?

In the above note by Zydor, it does not mention about half-integral weight modular forms, instead it consider sum over Heegner points. Maybe this is the right classical statement that corresponds to the above adelic statement, but I still don't get why this corresponds to the toric periods.

---

*Edit*: Based on [Kimball's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440640) and [Peter Humphrey's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440638/waldspurgers-formula-and-toric-periods-classical-and-adelic-versions#comment1136548_440638), they are separate theorems and the second is NOT an adelic version of the first one. For completion, here are the list of relevant papers from Waldspurger (found on mathscinet)

- Correspondance de Shimura ((J. Math. Pures. Appl. 1980): *Adelic* version of Shimura correspondence.
- Sur les coefficients de Fourier des formes modulaires de poids demi-entier (J. Math. Pures. Appl. 1981): *Classical* Waldspurger's formula for half-integral weight modular forms and $L$-values.
- Sur les valeurs de certaines fonctions $L$ automorphes en leur centre de symetrie (Compositio, 1985): Above *adelic* results on toric periods and $L$-values.
- Correspondences de Shimura et quaternions (Forum math, 1991): Shimura correspondence between $\mathrm{Mp}_2$ and $D^\times$, viewed as a composition of the original Shimura correspondence and Jacquet-Langlands correspondence?

Comment: For $F = \mathbb{Q}$, the toric periods can be written as a sum over Heegner points (if the torus corresponds to an imaginary quadratic field) or a sum over cycle integrals over closed geodesics (if the torus corresponds to a real quadratic field). The adelic-to-classical correspondence in the latter setting is explained in some detail in Section 6 of this paper of Popa: https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X06002259. See also Section 6 of this recent paper of myself and Nordentoft: https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05890

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two separate theorems, proved in different papers of Waldspurger (I think in 1980/1981 and 1985, respectively), so you shouldn't conflate them.  The first theorem can be viewed as an "$L$-value correspondence between automorphic representations of GL(2) and Mp(2) (Shimura correspondence), and the second between automorphic representations of GL(2) and $B^\times$ where $B$ is a quaternion algebra (Jacquet-Langlands correspondence).

So really Waldspurger proved a triangle of relations between three things: $L$-values of quadratic twists, Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight forms, and toric periods.

Comment: Thanks! Now everything gets much clear. For the last sentence, do you mean that one can essentially find a sort of formula between Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight modular forms and toric periods of Shimura correspondent, by combining two results? I wonder if there's such a statement in a classical context, if one consider toric periods as sum over Heegner points as Peter Humphries mentioned.

Comment: Yes.  For instance, a recent paper of Suzuki, Wakatsuki and Yokoyama writes down an explicit relation between Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight forms and toric periods.

Comment: I believe that the paper you mentioned is *Distribution of Toric Periods of Modular Forms on Definite Quaternion Algebras* (Corollary 3.5). Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi, I just realized that I forgot to ask this question - if the above two statements are separated, then what is the adelic analogue of Waldspurger's formula for half-integral weight modular forms? Can Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight modular forms be interpreted as certain periods of corresponding automorphic representations of $\mathrm{Mp}_{2}$ or $\widetilde{\mathrm{GL}}_{2}$? If it is, could you suggest any relevant references? I believe this would follow from S-W-Y's paper, but I think there might be previous work on it.